# Does cement board go behind the flange or in front in a tub installation?

Tags: tile

See the image here of the current tub.

[image]

Comment: At a minimum, the waterproofing must go over the flange. More details on how you're waterproofing and what kind of finish material you're installing would be most helpful

Comment: Are you implying that you intend to put cement board over the drywall that's there? That's non-standard and inadvisable. At a minimum you'll want a moisture barrier over the drywall, but all your screws will wreak havoc on that. I'd be starting over with some furring strips on the framing. Please update as requested.

Comment: Where's the spout??

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do this is to set the tub prior to drywall. Then the cement board goes on and stops at the top of the tub flange. The tile would then go on the cement board and span over the flange and seal to the tub top surface (usually grout and caulking).

The tub flange protects any water that may get behind the tile from going back behind the tub.

As you have the drywall already installed, it looks like you can apply the cement board on top of that  and stop it at the top of the tub flange then proceed as stated above. You will have to come up with a way to finish the long vertical edges where the tile/ cement board ends. It will look like an old "mud set" tile job.

It appears that your back right corner of the tub may be too far away from the drywall to allow the finish side of the concrete board to protrude beyond the flange. I think you are going to have to fur that wall out behind the cement board in the corner for the tile to work properly.